# .net Logging assembling

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I needed to write a custom logger for .net. Although I already did it I am not completely happy because I fail to understand how Filters are called into the ILoggingProvider or ILoggerFactory. I'm not refering to how filters work, but how my filter is feeded from appsettings without myself configuring that, like for example ConsoleLogger, writing the ext method AddConsole is enough.

I've done some researching but been unable to find useful info. Microsoft docs. I even looked into github at logging repo. Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: Can you give an example of what exactly is unclear? I kind of fail to understand where exactly you get lost.

Comment: I am trying to understand how filter works. in consolelogger they declare a func delegate named filter in order to decide if the message is logged or not. i fail to understand how that delegate is passed to the logger.

Comment: Can you give some references? So we can talk about some specific code?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console/ConsoleLogger.cs is the code of consolelogger. I want to know how filter is passed when one calls from DI iloggerfactory i.e. factory.createlogger();

Comment: Ah, I see. There, the `filter` is a Function delegate. It takes a `string` and a `LogLevel` and returns a `bool`. Where the string is the category. So it is a function about which the logger does not care, really, how it works. It is just supposed to tell him if he is allowed to log or not. That decision is made based on the category and level he is supposed to log.

Comment: ^^ It powers `IsEnabled` which in turn is used in `Log` as `if (!IsEnabled(logLevel)) { return; }`. So it is passed to `ConsoleLogger` through the Constructor. And I guess this is the part where you get lost? How the Factory comes up with an implementation for the `filter` Function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Fildor, exactly that is what I mean. Thanks!!